# Django - filter objects (multiple categories of the same model)

Tags: django

I have Site.model with has category, category1 values:
Site A:
 - category1
 - category2
Site B:
 - category1
 - category3

I would like to filter objects in particular category to show only related sites (for example in category1 there should be Site A and Site B, in category3 - only Site B). Now my code looks like:

```
class SiteList():

    def __init__(self, category_slug, subcategory_slug=None):
        self.cat_slug = category_slug
        self.subcat_slug = subcategory_slug

    def get_context(self):
        context = {}
        if self.subcat_slug is None:
            category = Category.objects.get(slug=self.cat_slug)
            sites = Site.objects.filter(category=category, is_active=True)
            subcategory = SubCategory.objects.values().filter(category=category)
        else:
            category = Category.objects.get(slug=self.cat_slug)
            subcategory = SubCategory.objects.filter(category=category
                                                     ).get(slug=self.subcat_slug)
            sites = Site.objects.filter(subcategory=subcategory, is_active=True)
        context['subcategory'] = subcategory
        print(subcategory)
        context['category'] = category
        context['sites'] = sites
        return context
```

Is it possible to write something like??:

```
sites = Site.objects.filter(category=category or category1=category, is_active=True)
```

I don't have any idea how can I filter sites to display proper objects.

This is my Site model:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    subcategory = ChainedForeignKey(
        'SubCategory',
        chained_field='category',
        chained_model_field='category',
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    description = models.TextField()

    keywords = MyTextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, editable=False)
    url = models.URLField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    category1 = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='category', blank=True, null=True)
    subcategory1 = ChainedForeignKey(
        'SubCategory',
        chained_field='category1',
        chained_model_field='category',
        related_name='subcategory',
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True, blank=True, null=True)

    group = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=(('podstawowy', 'podstawowy'),
                                                     ('premium', 'premium')), default='podstawowy')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('site', args=[str(self.category.slug),
                                     str(self.subcategory.slug), str(self.id)])

    def get_thumb(self):
        host = urlparse(self.url).hostname
        if host.startswith('www.'):
            host = host[4:]
        thumb = 'http://free4.pagepeeker.com/v2/thumbs.php?size=s&url=' + host
        return thumb

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Strony"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and my Category view:

```
def category(request, category_slug):
    context = {}
    try:
        context = SiteList(category_slug).get_context()
        # tagi dla kategorii
        tags = Tags(category_slug).all_tags()
        context['tags'] = tags
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("There is no such category")
    return render(request, 'mainapp/category.html', context)
```

Thanks for any clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to write something like??:
>
> ```
>    sites = Site.objects.filter(category=category or category1=category, is_active=True)
> ```

Yes, use the [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) object when you want to use `or`:

> If you need to execute more complex queries (for example, queries with **`OR`** statements), you can use **`Q`** objects.
>
> A **`Q`** object (**`django.db.models.Q`**) is an object used to encapsulate a collection of keyword arguments. These keyword arguments are specified as in “Field lookups” above.

```
from django.db.models import Q
sites = Site.objects.filter(
    Q(category=category) | Q(category1=category), 
    is_active=True)
```

Comment: Works great:) Thank you.